# How to define a callback with parameters without closure and use in PHP?

Tags: php, lambda, closures, anonymous-function

In PHP in order to define a callback a closure can be used and the tool for passing static parameters is the `use` directive.

```
class MyClass {
    public function foo($x) {
        echo $x;
    }
    public function bar() {
        $x = '123';
        $callback = function () use ($x) {
            $this->foo($x);
        };
        $callback();
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->bar();
```

Is it possible / How to avoid the anonymous function and replace it by a method?

```
class MyClass {
    public function foo($x) {
        echo $x;
    }
    public function baz() {
        $x = '567';
        // There is no function with the name create_user_func.
        // Just to show, what I'm looking for.
        $callback = create_callback([$this, 'foo'], $params = [$x]);
        $callback();
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->baz();
```

---

**EDIT**:

Some additional / backgroud info (to make clear, what I want to achieve and why -- and to avoid misanderstandings):

In my concrete case I need to pass the callback to a method of a framework. That means: I cannot / may not affect the way it gets called.

The method accepts only the callback itself, no arguments for the callback. That means, the callback has to "know"/provide the static parameters (and their values) it needs.

It's exactly, what the `use` directive solves. But I have multiple callback definitions in my method, and the method is getting long. So I want to move the logic of the callbacks to separate methods.

Comment: Check out this method: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunction.invoke.php. Maby this is what you are looking for?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. "args - The passed in argument list. It accepts a variable number of arguments which are passed to the function much like call_user_func() is." But actually other than the `call_user_func()` the `ReflectionFunction#_construct(...)` doesn't accept an array like `[$this, 'foo']`. It's still possible to pass arguments, but only non-static args, no static / early bound arguments.

Comment: Basically you're trying to emulate Javascript's `someFunc.bind(null, x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I have multiple callback definitions in my method, and the method is getting long. So I want to move the logic of the callbacks to separate methods.

This is a perfect example for the magic method [`__invoke()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke)

For each callback you need, extract the functionality and the properties it uses into a new class. Put the code into the `__invoke()` method of the new class, initialize all the properties it needs into its `__construct()` and you're ready to go.

The code:

```
class MyClass {
    public function bar() {
        $x = '123';
        // Create the callback, pass the values it needs to initialize
        $callback = new ActionFoo($x);
        // Call the callback without arguments
        $callback();
    }
}

class ActionFoo {
    private $x;
    public function __construct($x) {
        $this->x = $x;
    }
    public function __invoke() {
        echo($this->x);
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's fair to say that you're trying to emulate Javascript's `bind` method. The problem with this in PHP is that functions are not first class citizens or objects, so something like `->bind($x)` is not possible. There's also no way to pass additional parameters for a [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). So you're going to *have* to wrap it in *something*.

A more reusable method would be to write an appropriate class:

```
class CallbackWrapper {
    protected $callable,
              $args;

    public function __construct(callable $callable, array $args) {
        $this->callable = $callable;
        $this->args     = $args;
    }

    public function __invoke() {
        call_user_func_array($this->callable, $this->args);
    }
}

giveMeACallback(new CallbackWrapper([$this, 'foo'], [$x]));
```

Or you just simplify the construction of anonymous functions:

```
function make_callback(callable $callable, array $args) {
    return function () use ($callable, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array($callable, $args);
    };
}

giveMeACallback(make_callback([$this, 'foo'], [$x]));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1. **Using a helper function.**

Code:

```
class MyClass {
    private $x;

    public function foo() {
        echo $this->x;
    }
    public function bar() {
        $this->x = '123';
        anon($this);
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->bar();

function anon($obj) {
    $obj->foo();
}
```

2. **Using** `call_user_func`.

Code:

```
class MyClass {
    private $x;

    public function foo() {
        echo $this->x;
    }
    public function bar() {
        $this->x = '123';
        call_user_func([$this, 'foo']);
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->bar();
```

3. **If for some reason you don't want to use member variables, you can pass the arguments with** `call_user_func_array`.

Code:

```
class MyClass {
    private $x;

    public function foo($x) {
        echo $x;
    }
    public function bar() {
        $x = '123';
        call_user_func_array([$this, 'foo'], [$x]);
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->bar();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Raphael! But your answer is about the _calling_. My question is about the _building_ a callback with non-static parameters (using a method "reference" instead of an anonymous function). Please see my question update with the additional / backround info.

Comment: I'm confused.  Some questions to clarify.  1.  Does `$callback = create_callback([$this, 'foo'], $params = [$x]);
        $callback();`  work for you the way you want?  2.  If it does work the way you want, are you only looking to extract this logic out to another method?

Comment: The method `create_callback(...)` doesn't exist in PHP. `$callback = create_callback([$this, 'foo'], $params = [$x])` is only a kind of pseudocode to make clear, what I'm looking for. The `$callback` needs to be passed to the framework method I've written about. So I'm looking for a way to build / define a callback / closure with non-static / early bound arguments (but without an anonymous function -- in order to refactor the code and avoid an endless long method with multiple closure definition blocks).

Comment: @deceze has written an answer which defines a callback that can be passed to your framework.